# Axios get method having network error and Cors policy with status code 200

Tags: vue.js

When I call  axios get always goes directly to the catch block displaying a network error in the console, Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://13.234.115.246/customers_log.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

but the status code is 200

Request URL: http://13.234.115.246/customers_log.php
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 13.234.115.246:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

how to slove this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before a `GET`/`POST` is performed, the webbrowser will first do a "preflight request". That's a request of type `OPTIONS`, which is intended just to verify which options are allowed/possible.

The preflight request is succesful (i.e. status code 200) but tells you that CORS is not allowed. So, the actual `GET`/`POST`/... request will not be executed. Why not?

- the webserver that hosts your webpages is not the same server as the one that provides the REST services. And that could indicate a security issue.
- the webserver is configured to notify your client about this.

I guess you are still in development phase. So, you basically you just need to enable CORS on your backend server if you want to allow this.

## for node

e.g. you could add something like the following if you use NodeJS.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

## for php

For php see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers).

Comment: I am writting this code- axios.get('http://13.234.115.246/customers_log.php',{
             headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
               'content-type': 'application/json',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            },

          })
            .then(function (response) {
              // handle success
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            })

Comment: this Origin: ... stuff should not be on your front-end request, it should be on your back-end . i.e. in your php code. --> I added an example for php

Comment: As per you say i added this on my backend but still getting same.

Comment: @ShrJoshi There is another thread on stackoverflow, which features a giant `cors()` method for your PHP backend which is probably more robust. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers

Comment: thank you now its working i am adding in php heders-:  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");